# Does chamois creme affect the life of cycling shorts?

Tags: chamois, chamois-creme, shorts

Does chamois creme have any effect on the life of cycling shorts? I know it's made to be used for cycling but does it make the chamois (or maybe a synthetic one) wear out faster?

Comment: I'm not certain either, which is why I use it only when I think I'll have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a followup to my answer on ["Picking Chamois Creme"](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1760/picking-chamois-creme/1764#1764), BodyGlide hasn't affected the life of my shorts so far after 3 years of heavy use.  But it never completely washes out either.  My experience with other products is too limited to comment.